# Python Pandas Strange Groupby Behavior depending on boolean criteria and merging

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand a particular result when conducting the following data manipulations.  I noticed this on a large, private dataset and haven't been able to replicate it on a smaller dummy set of data.  Nonetheless I've included what the code is below.

Summary (to make the code easier to read)

1. have a transaction-level dataframe
2. define transaction-level criteria on this dataframe
3. merge the dataframe with results from another data manipulation (from the same dataframe)
4. apply the  transaction level criteria to the dataframe
5. `groupby` certain fields, and then reset the index.

The issue is that the # of rows returned after step 5 is different if I switch the order of steps 2 and 3.

Below is the code:

Sequence 1:

```
#1:  The dataset
df = rawdf.copy()

#2:  Define the Criteria
c1 = (df.year == '2000')
c2 = (df.personid != '12345')
c3 = (df.tallflag != 'T' )
c4 = (df.wealthyflag != 'B')
c5 = (df.freefood != 'F')
c6 = (df.duplicaterecord == 'N')
c7 = (df.match == 'Y')
c8 = (df.nbrpets != 0)
c9 = (df.dollars != 0)

critorder = c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 & c9
legitnames = ['bob','dan','mike','horatio']
critnames = (df.firstname.isin(legitnames))
legitcountycode = ['a','b','c','d']
critcode = (df.countycode.isin(critcode))

crit1 = critorder & critnames & critcode

#3:  Adjust the dataframe via a merge
yearspresent = df.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: \
';'.join(x['year'].order(ascending=True).drop_duplicates())).reset_index()
yearspresent.columns = ['parentnbr','yearspresent']
df = df.merge(yearspresent, how='left', on ='parentnbr')

#4 & 5:  Apply the criteria, then groupby
slctfields = ['year','firstname','lastname','city','state','country', \
'parentorg', 'dollars', 'nbrpets']
grp = ['year','firstname','lastname','city','state','country','parentorganization']

df[slt][crit1].groupby(grp).aggregate(sum).reset_index()
```

Sequence 2:  same as sequence 1, but with step 2 and 3 switched.

The final step:

```
df[slt][crit1].groupby(grp).aggregate(sum).reset_index()
```

produces 2 differently sized dataframes across the two Sequences.  I tried to join the final step of the two sequences to see which rows exist in Sequence 1 and not Sequence 2, but a left merge between the two does not show any differences.

I'm pretty sure defining the criteria after adjusting the dataframe with the merge is the right way to go, but I want to understand why the results are different if nothing is changing in the underlying, transaction level dataframe other than the addition of a new column.

Has anyone run into similar issues, or can shed light on this?  Let me know if this explanation isn't clear and I can elaborate as much as possible.

---

## SOLUTION:

I think I may have figured it out.  The docs mention that whenever joining columns on columns, the indexes *will be ignored*.  after merging via a left join, the post-merge dataframe does not match the pandas-generated index of the left dataframe, despite being the same size.

since defining the boolean index before the join has the original index, applying that criteria to the post-merged dataframe results in mismatch errors.

My mistake was thinking the index of the left dataframe is maintained after a left join.
I'm fairly confident this is the answer but I'll leave this question unchecked in case anyone can shed more insight.  Will officially answer it myself in the next day or so.

Comment: It's 5.5 years later. Please post your solution, accept it, edit the question to be much more concise and also reproducible, i.e. we don't want most of your `rawdf`, but we do need a minimal snippet that illustrates the issue.